# What is the best way to test for significance for a value that is tested once between two users

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, t-test

I want to know if there is significant variation between two users who are testing the activity of an enzyme. 
Example, user 1 tests sample 1 with a result of 100. User 2 tests sample 1 with a results of 104. Users only test the sample once.
Do I perform a two tailed t test and compare the average of the two users for the total sample set?

Comment: If each user only tests the sample once then there is no way to compare the two users because you cannot calculate the variability for each user.

Comment: Thank you. I thought this was the case, but I had a colleague insist one could calculate the variability

Comment: If you took multiple measurements per user then you can do a two sample t-test: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat200/node/60.  But as mentioned, you cannot calculate the standard deviation for each user.

Answer (score 2):

If there is only 1 sample measured measured once, then you have just a single data point and you have very little basis for comparing the two users.

However, the question mentions a 'total sample set', which suggests that there are multiple samples (each measured once). In this situation, the two users can definitely be compared. A t-test would be a reasonable choice, but given this scenario a better framework may be an [equivalence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test). As the wikipedia link points out, equivalence tests are not very different, and can take the form of 'two-one-sided t-tests’ (TOST). A paired TOST approach would probably suit this problem well.